# Oracle connect by root equivalent to PostgreSQL in view

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration, recursive-query

I'm migrating an Oracle database over to PostgreSQL. I use ora2pg to migrate the database over But some of the views with 'CONNECT_BY_ROOT' failed. Are there any online application that convert Oracle views over to PostgreSQL? Here is one of the views

This is the view in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_group_descendants (id, name, descendant_group_id, descendant_group_name) AS WITH RECURSIVE q AS (SELECT id,
                       NAME,
                       ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID,
                       NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME
            FROM GROUPS
            where PRIVATE_FLAG = 'N'
            union all
            SELECT m.ID, m.name, m.ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID, m.NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME
            FROM GROUPS m
            JOIN q ON q.ID = m.ID)
    SELECT ID, NAME, ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID, NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME from q;
```

This is the view I created in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_group_descendants (id, name, descendant_group_id, descendant_group_name) AS WITH RECURSIVE q AS (SELECT id,
                           NAME,
                           ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID,
                           NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME
                FROM GROUPS
                where PRIVATE_FLAG = 'N'
                union all
                SELECT m.ID, m.name, m.ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID, m.NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME
                FROM GROUPS m
                JOIN q ON q.ID = m.ID)
        SELECT ID, NAME, ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID, NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME from q;
```

The view created this way but not able to get any output

On oracle 
SQL> select count(*) from view_group_descendants;

### COUNT(*)

```
  4932
```

On PostgreSQL Just hangs

```
tufdv=# select count(*) from view_group_descendants;
```

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question.  Ask another question and provide sample data and desired results, as well as this query (you can also edit this question, if you like).  `connect by root` is totally Oracle-specific.  There are other ways to accomplish this in ANSI SQL and Postgres, but it is not a 1-1 translation.

Comment: I did find an article to use 'with recursive" "equivalent query in PostgreSQL, use the WITH RECURSIVE". But not sure have to apply in my Create view statement

Comment: . . That is the right answer, but without sample data and desired results, you just make it harder for anyone to  help you.

Comment: I think I solved it

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_group_descendants (id, name, descendant_group_id, descendant_group_name, descendant_flag) AS 
WITH RECURSIVE q AS (SELECT id,
                           NAME,
                           ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID,
                           NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME,
                           PUBLIC_FLAG DESCENDANT_FLAG,
                           PARENT_GROUP
                FROM GROUPS
                where PRIVATE_FLAG = 'N'
                union all
                SELECT m.ID,
                        m.name,
                        m.ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID,
                        m.NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME,
                        m.PUBLIC_FLAG DESCENDANT_FLAG,
                        m.PARENT_GROUP
                FROM GROUPS m
                JOIN q ON q.PARENT_GROUP = m.ID)
        SELECT ID, NAME, ID DESCENDANT_GROUP_ID, NAME DESCENDANT_GROUP_NAME, DESCENDANT_FLAG from q;
```

I can select from Oracle and PostgreSQL with the same output